# solr service shut down for no apprent reason

Tags: solr, solarium

I'm using the **solr5.3.1** for full text searching.And I'm using **PHP with** [solarium library](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium) to communicate with solr service.It is doing well in most of the time.**But it was shut down twice for no reason.I check the log files,and find no error message**.So I was curious to know is there are some reasons will cause solr to shut down itself? I can show you more detail information if you need to help me solve the problem,just tell me in the comments.Thanks so much!

Comment: any JVM log generated?

Comment: @sidgate where to find JVM logs?I only checked log files in **{solr_install_path}/server/logs**,which contains solr log and solr gc log.And I found **none error msg**

Comment: Check the syslog - maybe your JVM is getting killed because of OOM - that would usually leave little trace in the application itself.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks a lot! I have checked the syslog, and found this `Out of memory: Kill process 23076 (java) score 49 or sacrifice child`. It is exactly the OOM who killed my solr process.I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @MatsLindh's comment! I checked my syslog(/var/log/messages),and found this `Out of memory: Kill process 23076 (java) score 49 or sacrifice child`.**JVM was killed because of OOM**.

now, I run `echo -17 > /proc/{solr_process_pid}/oom_adj` to avoid solr process being killed again.